# Make text show up in the top of an input?

Tags: html

I have an input box

```
   <INPUT TYPE="text"  style="width: 600px; height: 250px; background-color: transparent; text-align:left;"VALUE="Test">
```

But "Test" shows up in the center left of the input box. How can I make "test" show up in the upper left corner of the box?

Comment: you'd want to use textarea for that.. an input box like that is only meant for one line of text so it will automatically middle align it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it what you want ?

`<textarea style="width: 600px; height: 250px;">Test</textarea>`

Comment: If I were to use textarea how would I change the value of the textarea with javascript?

Comment: document.getElementById('textareaId').value = 'new value'; or with jQuery: jQuery('textarea').val('new value');

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```html
  <textarea rows="50" cols="200">Test</textarea>
```

Using `width` and `height` can get messy, especially with textareas.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the position of the value inside an input with padding.

Working example:

```html
 <input type="text" style="padding: 5px 5px 40px 5px;width: 600px; " value="Test">
```